# Matching regex groups (with or's) and special characters with Python's re module

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split apart strings like the titles below, and match names and then any additional information, either in brackets/braces or after a dash (regular, m/n dashes, horizontal bar).

The regex seems fine to me and I'm able to test it on other regex testers, but it's not working when run with Python.

There's a couple of weird things going on. The first dashed title seems to have matched, but the `addition_a` group doesn't contain the correct string. Also, for some reason, any special character like the various dashes aren't matching at all. The coding for the script is utf-8 so I'm assuming the dashes in the raw regex string should work okay, but they're not.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
titles = [
    'Spaced (News)',
    'Angry Birds [Game]',
    'Cheats - for all games', # dash
    'Cheats – for all games', # ndash
    'Cheats — for all games', # mdash
    'Cheats ― for all games'  # horizontal bar
]
regex = re.compile(r'^(?P<name>.+)\s+(([-–—―]\s+(?P<addition_a>.+))|([\(\[](?P<addition_b>.+)[\)\]]))$')
for title in titles:
    data = {}
    match = regex.match(title.strip())
    if match:
        data['name'] = match.group('name')
        try:
            data['addition'] = match.group('addition_a')
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:
            data['addition'] = match.group('addition_b')
        except IndexError:
            pass
    print data
```

Output:

```
{'addition': 'News', 'name': 'Spaces'}
{'addition': 'Game', 'name': 'Angry Birds'}
{'addition': None, 'name': 'Cheats'}
{}
{}
{}
```

Comment: Whoops, spotted that I left the `IndexError` catching from when I was accessing groups by a numeric index! Doh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use unicode literals. Otherwise, `[-–—―]` matches `-`, `\xe2`, `\x80`, `\x93`, `\xe2`, `\x80`, `\x94`, `\xe2`, `\x80`, `\x95` instead of `-`, `–`, `—`, `―`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
titles = [
    u'Spaced (News)',
    u'Angry Birds [Game]',
    u'Cheats - for all games', # dash
    u'Cheats – for all games', # ndash
    u'Cheats — for all games', # mdash
    u'Cheats ― for all games'  # horizontal bar
]
regex = re.compile(ur'^(?P<name>.+)\s+(([-–—―]\s+(?P<addition_a>.+))|([\(\[](?P<addition_b>.+)[\)\]]))$')
for title in titles:
    match = regex.match(title.strip())
    if match:
        data = {}
        data['name'] = match.group('name')
        data['addition'] = match.group('addition_a') or match.group('addition_b')
        print data
```

Output:

```
{'addition': u'News', 'name': u'Spaced'}
{'addition': u'Game', 'name': u'Angry Birds'}
{'addition': u'for all games', 'name': u'Cheats'}
{'addition': u'for all games', 'name': u'Cheats'}
{'addition': u'for all games', 'name': u'Cheats'}
{'addition': u'for all games', 'name': u'Cheats'}
```

---

```
>>> r'[–]'
'[\xe2\x80\x93]'
>>> re.findall(r'[–]', '–')
['\xe2', '\x80', '\x93']
>>> re.findall(ur'[–]', u'–')
[u'\u2013']
>>> print re.findall(ur'[–]', u'–')[0]
–
```

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense, I wasn't aware that you could specify a string literal to be a unicode raw string! I also accidentally left those try/catch blocks from when I was accessing groups by index as opposed to by name. Using the `or` for the addition group is much cleaner ;-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall, I forgot to mention that `match.group('addition_a')` always return something (str/None) even if there no `addition_a` group match. Same for `addition_b`.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode has "characters" or "symbols" which take up more than one byte, Python is not so good at understanding this concept and so sometimes has some hiccups. You can do one of the following things:

You can try to make sure all the strings you are parsing are unicode, if you are in control of those strings it should be simple - for your example, just add the `u` indicator to the start of the string like so:

```
u'Spaced (News)',
u'Angry Birds [Game]',
u'Cheats - for all games', # dash
u'Cheats – for all games', # ndash
u'Cheats — for all games', # mdash
u'Cheats ― for all games'  # horizontal bar
```

And also add it to your regex like so:

```
ur'^(?P<name>.+)\s+(([-–—―]\s+(?P<addition_a>.+))|([\(\[](?P<addition_b>.+)[\)\]]))$'
```

Otherwise, or if you are not in control, you can make a single small modification which - while not being totally proper - will work. That change is to accept multiple characters from the set `[-–—―]`, not just a single one by doing `[-–—―]+`:

```
r'^(?P<name>.+)\s+(([-–—―]+\s+(?P<addition_a>.+))|([\(\[](?P<addition_b>.+)[\)\]]))$'
```

Either of these options will result in what you want.

The first will result in unicode results:

```
>>> 
{'addition': u'News', 'name': u'Spaced'}
{'addition': u'Game', 'name': u'Angry Birds'}
{'addition': None, 'name': u'Cheats'}
{'addition': None, 'name': u'Cheats'}
{'addition': None, 'name': u'Cheats'}
{'addition': None, 'name': u'Cheats'}
```

The second in regular strings:

```
>>> 
{'addition': 'News', 'name': 'Spaced'}
{'addition': 'Game', 'name': 'Angry Birds'}
{'addition': None, 'name': 'Cheats'}
{'addition': None, 'name': 'Cheats'}
{'addition': None, 'name': 'Cheats'}
{'addition': None, 'name': 'Cheats'}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, makes total sense! I wasn't aware that you could have a unicode raw string. You learn something new everyday ;-)

Answer (score 2):

And a slightly more "sledge hammery" way is to change the entire re to be "some words and spaces until it's not, and then the rest". this also avoids the optional `additional_a` and `additional_b` named groups and the try/except logic.

Example:

```
for title in titles:
    data = dict(zip(['name', 'addition'], (m.strip() for m in re.findall('([\w\s]+)', title))))
    print data
```

Outputs:

```
{'addition': 'News', 'name': 'Spaced'}
{'addition': 'Game', 'name': 'Angry Birds'}
{'addition': 'for all games', 'name': 'Cheats'}
{'addition': 'for all games', 'name': 'Cheats'}
{'addition': 'for all games', 'name': 'Cheats'}
{'addition': 'for all games', 'name': 'Cheats'}
```

Comment: This is really interesting. While it's not quite suitable for my purposes, it doesn't half demonstrate how amazing Python is! Thanks for this.